# If statement within for Loop

Tags: r

Below is a toy model for something that is causing me problems.  I have a vector of T's and F's.  I want to loop through this vector and if the sum of the last 3 elements is >= 1 (which means at least 1 of them is TRUE), I assign an element in the empty vector as 1, otherwise I assign an element in the empty vector as 0.  In this way, as the for loop iterates through the starting vector, I fill in the empty vector with 1's and 0's.  The problem I'm having is an error, which I'll paste below.

```
two_true <- c(T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F)

look_bac <- 3

no_signal1 <- c()
for(i in 1:length(two_true)) {
        if(sum(two_true[i:(i+look_bac-1)]) >= 1) {
                no_signal1[i] <- 1 
        } else {
                        no_signal1[i] <- 0
                }
}
```

Running this gives me the following error:

*Error in if (sum(two_true[i:(i + look_bac - 1)]) >= 1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed*

I don't seem to get this as the condition for the if statement is clearly of the TRUE or FALSE variety.

I know there are probably many other ways to create this new vector, but I'm trying to learn R basics, so any help using the tools above (if statements and for loops) would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: When debugging a loop, it's good to know if the problem happens only on certain iterations. Put  a `print(i)` command inside your loop, run everything, and see how far the loop gets before the error. Then, when you see that perhaps the problem happens when `i` is 20 or 21, set `i` to one of those values and run the offending line: `sum(two_true[i:(i+look_bac-1)]) >= 1`. You can whittle it down and find the problem, `two_true[i:(i+look_bac-1)]` and think about why it doesn't work for the value of `i`.

Comment: because when your i is 20 and later, your if statement will return NA, that's why you get the error message.

Comment: First comment: *how to fish*; second comment *here's your fish*.

Comment: Fourth comment: I could go for some fish.

Comment: Time to close this fish fry.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  This was enormously useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the fishermen in the comments have already pointed out (@Gregor, @Mike Fang), your summation returns NA for the last elements of your vector, as there is an NA in your sum for `i=20`: `sum(c(FALSE, FALSE, NA))`.

Solution -  add the `na.rm=TRUE` option to `sum()`:

```
if(sum(two_true[i:(i+look_bac-1)], na.rm=TRUE) >= 1) {
```

However, R is not really a friendly environment for loops as there is a fierce enemy of the loop: the great house of the `apply` functions, which usually outrun any loop in a contest of speed:

```
library(zoo)
as.numeric(rollapply(two_true, 3 ,sum, partial=TRUE, align="left")>0)
```

Returns the same as your loop in a single line:

```
> as.numeric(rollapply(two_true, 3 ,sum, partial=TRUE, align="left")>0)
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
> no_signal1
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, summarising, welcome to R and meet our friendly `apply` functions!